# Changing state value in async event function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component:

```
const Calendar = ({ onEventDrag }) => {
  const [editable, setEditable] = useState(true);

  const eventChange = async event => {
    setEditable(false);
    console.log('before await');
    console.log(editable);
    await onEventDrag(event);
    console.log('after await');
    setEditable(true);
    console.log(editable);
  };

  return (
        <FullCalendar
          editable={editable}
          eventChange={eventChange}
        />
  );
};
```

`onEventDrag` is an `async` API call function passed through props to this component.

I want to set `editable` state value to `false` when `eventChange` function is called and only set it to `true` when `onEventDrag` async function returns something.

What console logs with this code currently:

```
before await
true
after await
true
```

Comment: You will also need to await the state change for `editable` so adding `await` before `setEditable(false)` and `setEditable(true)` (i.e. `await setEditable(false)`) will await the changes to state before calling `await onEventDrag(event)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state is an asynchronous operation, so it's expected that both of your `console.log`s will output `true`.  However, if you put `console.log(editable)` outside of `eventChange`, you should see it update appropriately on the next render.

Comment: Not only is `setEditable` asynchronous, but `editable` is a local variable captured in a closure. It won't be updated (it's a primitive defined with `const`), but on the next evaluation of the function it will be set again with the new value. By the time of the second `setEditable` call, the actual React-held value of `editable` is false since the second call is being evaluated asynchronously as well in a Promise (`async` / `await` are just syntactic sugar).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code works fine but the console logs the old value.

To understand this behavior you have to understand how closures work in javascript. When you define a function, any surrounding variables are made part of the function "scope". When you call `setEditable()`, react calls `Calendar()` again with a new state.

However, the `eventChange` function is still running! This is not a problem, since `setEditable` stays the same. However, the local variable `editable` will become outdated and no longer represent the actual state of the component.